MUI InputLabel not focused when corresponding TextField is focused
I have this in my code:
<FormControl>
  <InputLabel htmlFor="field-1">Field 1</InputLabel>
  <TextField id="field-1" .../>
</FormControl>

Why does the InputLabel not enter its focused (blue) variant when the TextField is focused?
The problem does not lie with styling, it lies with the fact that MUI doesn't set the 'Mui-focused' class on the input label when the text field is focused. If I swap out the TextField for a Select component, for example, the InputLabel is correctly forced into its focused state when the Select is focused.

And might I add: click the input labels does not focus the corresponding input component.

Can you give us more information or perhaps a codeboxsample? I tested the example you provided and I got it working. React version 18. @mui/material: 5.16.5
